# union is not working in django rest framwork?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have 2 table and want to implement union on result set?
i have crated one parent model and include its Pk AS FK in both child tables and implement following quires in rest framework

```
q1 = parent.objects.filter(chile_1__isnull=True).filter(chile_1__name='blog').values('chile_1__id').extra(select = {"id":"chile_1__id"})

    q2 = parent.objects.filter(chile_2__isnull=True).filter(chile_2__name='blog1').values('chile_2__id').extra(select = {"id":"chile_2__id"})
```

and even i have create alias of both children containing different fields name when i run following for union

```
q3 =  q1 | q2
```

showing following error

> TypeError: Merging 'GeoValuesQuerySet' classes must involve the same
>   values in each case.

will some one tell me how to get values of children using parent?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably Use a Model serializer. In order to serialize two or more different models you need to write a non-model based serializer. Then in the API get both and append them using itertools.chain to bind them and convert the result to a list. Then pass the list to the serializer... et voilà.

Hope this helps - its all in the Rest docs.

Edit: An example:

```
    class MyCustomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        object_pk = serializers.IntegerField(source='pk')
        name = serializers.CharField()
        goloc = serializers.CharField(source='get_geoloc')

    class MyCustomViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        serializer_class = MyCustomSerializer
        def list(self, request):
            mylist = []
            # q1 and q2 querysets need still to be fetched...
            for o in q1:
                mylist.append(o)
            for o in q2:
                mylist.append(o)
            queryset = mylist
            serializer = MyCustomSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: i'm using model base sterilizer. can i use both model base serialize and non-model based serialize in the same application?

Comment: Yes you can! I highly recommend that you read the tutorial and api guide for rest, Did I answer your question? All the best

Comment: @phil this error when i tried 'list' object has no attribute '_clone'

Comment: Sorry - to few information. Please ask a separate question; Provide your relevant code and an error message.